# vim variable declaration and breaks

Tags: variables, vim, break

Normally I use "\n" to add extra information in an inputdialog window.

p.e.

```
let myvar = "How many characters do you want to add? \n (max. 10)"
let f = inputdialog(myvar)
```

The break works fine.

but when I add a variable in the text, the break doesn't work anymore:

```
let myvar = 'How many ' .a:type. ' do you want to add? \n (max. 10)'
let f = inputdialog(myvar)
```

The variable is a:type is inserted well but the break doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Use preview and read about markdown formatting.

Comment: @Zyx, What do you mean with preview?

Comment: when you write a question there is a preview below the textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of you examples work: you should have been using double strokes instead of single.

Comment: sorry, I changed the first one. I always use double strokes. When I insert a variable it doesn't work in double strokes, only with single strokes but with single strokes doesn't work the linebreak command: \n. What do do to let both work.

Comment: @Remonn: problem is somewhere else: inserting a variable like you do does work with double strokes, so provide an example that does not work.

Comment: @ZyX, can you please rewrite the 2nd function with double quotes in order to make VIM insert the variable a:type and execute also the break \n.    I tried everything but can't make them work both (variable + break).

Comment: @ZyX, found it. I have to put also double strokes around the variable and \n without quotes. :)

Comment: @Remonn I don't understand you. If in your second example you simply do `s/'/"/g`, it will work. If you put double strokes around variable, it won't (unless you mean that you changed first and last single strokes to double, but forgot about other single strokes).

Comment: @ZyX, yes you're right (see my previous message). Thank you for your help.